# How can I make select's blur event in iOS to match desktop?

Tags: javascript, ios, select, onblur

I have a custom FullDate field that's comprised of a Month (Select), Day (Numeric TextBox), and Year (Numeric TextBox).

I have inline validations set up to run when the user blurs out of the field as a whole. The problem is, on desktop, when you select something in a select box, you don't run inline validations until you tab out of the field or click on something else. On iOS, however, blur seems to fire as soon as you select an option in the select box.

Any good way to handle that?

http://jsfiddle.net/L5s3rq84/1/

```
<select name="colors" id="test">
    <option>RED</option>
    <option>GREEN</option>
    <option>YELLOW</option>
    <option>BLUE</option>
    <option>ORANGE</option>
</select>

<select name="colors" id="fake">
    <option>RED</option>
    <option>GREEN</option>
    <option>YELLOW</option>
    <option>BLUE</option>
    <option>ORANGE</option>
</select>

$("#test").on("blur", act);

function act() {
    alert("TESTING!");
}
```

Comment: Try to use "change" event.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't get a blur event at all. You have the following options:

to move to "change" (instead of "blur") event:
http://jsfiddle.net/73bynhjq/1/

```
$("#test").on("change", act);
```

or you can do additional click event that that fires "blur" :)